# Is It Possible To Join Two Unrelated Tables In MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two unrelated tables but i want to  join them into one query, is that possible?

This is how I did it using cross join but it did not work

```
table 1
|   ID  |   Amount  |
|   1   |    20     |
|   2   |    10     |
|   3   |    21     |
|   4   |    50     |


table 2
|   ID      |   Paid Value      |
|   011     |      5            |
|   052     |      2            |
```

//My tried Query

```
SELECT
    a.`Amount`,
    b.`Paid Value`
FROM
    `table 1` a 
CROSS JOIN
    `table 2` b
```

This is what i get in return using the above query

```
|   ID  |   Amount  | Paid Value    | 
|   1   |    20     |   5           |
|   2   |    10     |   2           |
|   3   |    21     |   5           |
|   4   |    50     |   2           |
```

However this is my expected results

```
|   ID  |   Amount  | Paid Value    | 
|   1   |    20     |   5           |
|   2   |    10     |   2           |
|   3   |    21     |   0           |
|   4   |    50     |   0           |
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Do you care what rows get matched?  If so, you need something that specifies the ordering.  Also, your cross join should be returning 8 rows, not 4.

Comment: Quit shouting.​ And you appear to have fundamentally misunderstood what tables _are_. They are not lexically ordered lists, like a data table drawn out on a piece of paper. They are _relations_ of data, with no inherent row ordering in storage. Both your attempt and your very requirement betray a lack of understanding here.

Answer (score 2):

You want to join by some implicit row number.  Let me assume that this is based on the ordering of the `id`s.  You can use variables to calculate the row number and then use that for the join:

```
select t1.id, t1.amount, coalesce(t2.paidvalue, 0)
from (select t1.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from table1 t1 cross join
           (select @rn := 0) vars
      order by id
     ) t1 left join
     (select t2.*, (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) as rn
      from table1 t2 cross join
           (select @rn2 := 0) vars
      order by id
     ) t2
     on t1.rn = t2.rn;
```